# Can not attach debugger to HTTP JVM, AMGR JVM is attached instead

Tags: java, xpages, lotus-domino

Domino is configured to allow remote debugging by notes.ini param:

```
JavaEnableDebug=1
JavaDebugOptions=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8703
```

Debug is tarted in Domino Designer/Eclipse to debug some XPages code. Debugger attaches to different JVM. As I discovered, it is JVM of AMGR which run Java agent previously. Disconnecting and reconnecting debugger does not help.

Only workaround is to shutdown/restart AMGR to be able to attach to HTTP JVM.

**Is it possible to set different ports for AMGR and HTTP debuggers?**

Comment: As far as I know remote debugging is for AMGR only. I suppose a quick test is to not load AMGR on the server and see if it attaches to the HTTP process (I'm guessing it won't).

Comment: @SimonO'Doherty Fortunately this works with HTTP Java and helps a lot with XPages development. Few people blogged about that. So with AMGR turned off everything works as designed (I assume :-)). My problem is about interference with AMGR JVM.

Comment: Interesting. Will look into that.

Comment: Too early in the morning.:) It should just work (walkthrough: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1xczmvd1bs0 ). Can you expand on what you are seeing in regards to AMGR intercepting?

Comment: have never seen this. maybe because I always use port 8000? have you tried that port?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spoke to development about this issue and it is a known issue (to them :) . When the Domino server starts up all JVMs (AMGR / HTTP) will attempt to connect to the port as per the debug settings. So which ever process grabs it first wins.

It is currently under investigation to see if you can have multiple ports (I don't have an SPR yet).

You can try changing the sequence of the SERVERTASKS setting in the notes.ini to launch the HTTP before the AMGR. Otherwise stop both processes and then start the one you want.

Answer (score 1):

I just found that:
https://support.hcltechsw.com/csm?id=kb_article&sysparm_article=KB0079805

Have JVM bind to an arbitrary port by omitting the address attribute in the JavaDebugOptions.
JavaDebugOptions=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n

instead of
JavaDebugOptions=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8000

The JVM would then pick a random port.
...