# lotus notes xpage debugging

Tags: debugging, xpages, lotus

I'm using xpages and lotus notes.
I've followed the guides mentioned from various sites about setting up debugging with lotus notes xpages javascript,
where

```
 JavaEnableDebug=1
 JavascriptEnableDebug=1
 JavaDebugOptions=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8000
```

has to be set up on workstation and on dev server.

Also, the port 8000 has to be enabled, and opened in default firewall on workstation and dev server.
And create a Javascript debug config on LN with ip address of dev server, and port 8000.

Also checking, port 8000 is not being used as per using netstat...
on workstation and on dev server,
and so I did...

Then soft restart workstation and dev server, loaded up LNotes and designer,
then using Chrome, I loaded my app for debugging,
then going back to LNotes while app is running and focused on the browser,
then trying to run my Debug config...
But debugger still does not connect, and keeps popping the help info screen.

So, what could I have missed?

Comment: i tried port 8701 but debugger still cannot connect.. or maybe i try up to port 8999 whichever will work.. (not efficient coding)

Comment: check if your server is listening on port 8000 with Netstat. If it is not listening there is something wrong with your notes.ini on the server. If the server is listening check with a network sniffer like wireshark if the connection request from the client reach the server.

Comment: I covered the debugger in a session for DanNotes / ICON UK a couple of years ago. Slides can be found here: https://www.slideshare.net/mobile/MarkLeusink/stop-debugging-me-17648393. Maybe that helps.

Comment: thanks Mark, i'll check that out..

Answer (score 2):

In Domino Designer you need to switch to the Debug tab and click on the bug to start your session.

[image]

I found it doesn't connect always directly. When you see only 2 threads it didn't. Click disconnect and connect again.

Once you see more threads you are good to go.  You also need to set some breakpoints otherwise it runs through

Comment: thanks stwissel, thing is, debugger couldn't connect, so no option to disconnect, i'll check on some more details

Comment: You have seen that guide: http://www.intec.co.uk/beginners-guide-to-the-java-debugger-and-tips-from-using-it-and-a-teaser/ and that issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15100261/can-not-attach-debugger-to-http-jvm-amgr-jvm-is-attached-instead -- Check your firewall setting